# How to query XML column convert to rows

Tags: sql

I have table with some XML column. How to convert XML column to rows?

```
SELECT RECID, DATE, STARTED
FROM F_SERVICE
```

Result:

```
RECID | DATE                                         | STARTED
------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
COB   | <c15>20190122</c15><c15 m="2">20190121</c15> | <c16>02/04/2019 22:06:37</c16><c16 m="2">02/04/2019 22:02:41</c16>
```

Expected result:

```
RECID | DATE     | STARTED
------+----------+--------------------
COB   | 20190122 | 02/04/2019 22:06:37
COB   | 20190121 | 02/04/2019 22:02:41
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: In standard SQL you would use `xmltable()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle database you can use the xmltable function to convert XML columns to rows like this:

```
SELECT t1.recid
    ,t1.cob_pos
    ,t1.cob_date
    ,t2.cob_time
FROM (
    SELECT t.recid
        ,xt.cob_date
        ,nvl(xt.cob_pos, 1) cob_pos
    FROM myTable t
        ,XMLTABLE('/row/c15' passing t.xml_column columns cob_date VARCHAR(8) path '/', cob_pos VARCHAR(3) path '@m') xt
    ) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t.recid
        ,xt.cob_time
        ,nvl(xt.cob_pos, 1) cob_pos
    FROM myTable t
        ,XMLTABLE('/row/c16' passing t.xml_column columns cob_time VARCHAR(50) path '/', cob_pos VARCHAR(3) path '@m') xt
    ) t2 ON t1.recid = t2.recid
    AND t1.cob_pos = t2.cob_pos
ORDER BY t1.recid
```

You basically create two tables, one contained the id and the dates, the other containing the id and the times. Then you join them on the id and the position of the record.